# Using one-click plugin upgrade feature securely on suexec server

Tags: plugins, updates, installation

I've been searching for a definitive answer to this question for a couple of hours but can't find anything.

I'm running multiple sites on a server using suexec. The owner and group of all files and directories is `root` with the exception of the `uploads` directory and subdirectories which are owned by the system user associated with the site. Let's call this user `user` for his discussion.

I'm trying to get the "one-click" plugin updates and installation to work but I am not having success. I have tried temporarily changing ownership of `wp-content` and all files and directories in `wp-content` to `user` and I have have double checked the execute and write permissions on all directories which are `755`.

None of this has worked.

The only thing that has worked is changing the ownership of all files and directories on my WP install to `user`. This is a gaping security hole (as I've learned the hard way) and I want to avoid doing this.

So what directories do I temporarily change ownership of to get one-click updates and installs working?

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a section specific to suexec file permissions.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions#Shared_Hosting_with_suexec)

Comment: I've seen that. With those settings, I still have the problem and It does not tell you how to work around the problem with not being able to perform the `direct` `FS_METHOD` (see below).

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the code inside `file.php`, I discovered you don't have to change the ownership of `file.php` (see original answer below for reference). Instead, you can add the following line to `wp-confg.php`:

`define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');`

This will force WordPress to use the `direct` method for retrieving the plugins.

You still must manually change the ownership of `wp-content` and `wp-content/plugins` directories to the owner to the suexec user the site runs under. It's probably a good idea to change these back once you have finished making your updates and/or installed new plugins.

Answer (score -1):

Well, after some trial and error and a hint from [WP documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#File_Ownership), I discovered that you have to change the ownership of the `wp-admin/includes/file.php` file to match the suexec user the site is running under.

You also have to change the ownership of the `wp-content` and the `plugins` directory below it (and probably the directory of any plugin you are looking to update as well).